# Overwriting text in file using FILE Statement

Tags: sas, overwrite

I have a data set, call it `Data1` with just one variable, `V1`, and from this I would like to save each entry in a text-file, do some stuff with the text-file, and then move on to the next entry. When the next entry is written to the text-file, I want it to overwrite the previous entry. I am using the FILE statement, but for some reason, it keeps appending the new entry to the old one. I have the following code:

```
data _null_;
  set Data1;
  do i = _N_;
    if i > 0 then do;
      file "myfile.txt";
      put V1;
    end;
  end;
run;
```

When I open myfile.txt, I see that the entries for all observations have been saved, one row for each. However, what I want is that only the last entry should be saved (I will add other stuff to the loop later, but what's important is that the old content is overwritten).

I tried adding the option "OLD" to the FILE statement, but I get a message saying that OLD is no longer supported. I am using SAS 9.4.

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Try replacing `put V1;` with `put @1 V1 @@;`, this should hold the cursor position after each data step loop and then restart writing at column 1. (Assumes V1 is of constant length, technically if the previous V1 value is longer then some of that text will remain)

Comment: Thank you so much! V1 is actually not of constant length (I assume you're meaning the number of characters in each entry of V1). So, you mean that if the last entry is of, say, 20 characters, while the previous is of 30, then the last 10 of the previous will remain when the last entry is written to the file?

Comment: Yes, that's exactly right. You could add: `filler=repeat(' ',200); put @1 filler @@; put @1 V1 @@;` Which would clear out the previous entry with whitespace. There are probably other ways to do this, hence my answering with a comment rather than an actual answer.

Comment: @mjsqu I think that's a perfectly good answer - the fact that it's not the best way doesn't make it not a good way.

Comment: Your problem statement doesn't make much sense to me.  Can you show an example input dataset and what it would produce in the output text file?

Comment: Why not just only write the last record? `data _null_; set data1 end=eof; file 'myfile.txt'; if eof then put v1; run;`

Comment: Tom, you're absolutely right: the problem does not make sense. Basically, I want to save each entry separately, then before moving on to the next entry, I am using some other statements concerning the external text file. This is the reason why I need to have them written to the file one at a time.

Comment: What does "save" mean if you are only writing the last record to the file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's hard to tell what you're trying to do exactly, but one possible answer is to use the `_FILE_` automatic variable.

```
data _null_;
  set sashelp.class;
  do i = 1 to _N_;
    if i > 0 then do;
      file "c:\temp\myfile.txt";
      _file_ = name;
    end;
  end;
run;
```

This is an advanced SAS technique known as *_FILE_ Magic*.  It's related to *_INFILE_ Magic*, a more well known technique, and is quite helpful if you'd like to do something such as use the powerful scanning tools available to `input` but not as readily available in functions (though that's less true now than it was 10 years ago; most of what you can do in input is now available via `scan`, `index`, `find`, etc.).  If that's why you want to do this, then you may want to use either `_FILE_` or `_INFILE_` depending on what you are doing exactly.  `_INFILE_` version which uses `sharebuffers` to allow you to read/write the same file:

```
data _null_;
  set sashelp.class;
  do i = 1 to _N_;
    if i > 0 then do;
      infile "c:\temp\myfile.txt" sharebuffers;
      file "c:\temp\myfile.txt";
      _infile_ = name;
    end;
  end;
run;
```

Search for papers on the topic to see more details; Mike Zdeb's [`_FILE_` Magic](http://www.lexjansen.com/nesug/nesug12/bb/bb07.pdf) (NESUG 2012), and Peter Crawford's [More `_INFILE_` Magic](http://www.lexjansen.com/views/2003/tipstech/tt05.pdf) (SUGI 28/2003) are excellent examples of these tools.

Comment: Apologies if the links look weird... no other way to get the _ around the variable unfortunately (other than making the whole link in code formatting).

Comment: Thank you Joe - this works. It does add some white space according (I guess) to the length of the previous entry, but I guess this is as good as it gets!

Answer (score 0):

As specified in the comments, this is a quick and dirty way of doing it with double trailing-at, and pointer position:

```
data _null_;
set Data1;
filler=repeat(' ',200);
file "myfile.txt";
  put @1 filler @@;
  put @1 V1 @@;
run;
```

Additions:

- The filler variable keeps 200 spaces (increase if more whitespace needed)
- The first `put` statement writes the whitespace to the first line in the file, the double trailing-at holds the pointer on the current line
- The second `put` statement writes the V1 value at the first column, overwriting some of the whitespace
- When the data step loops again, the first `put` writes whitespace to the first line...

etc.

Removed:

- Do loops, I'm not sure if they're required or were just an attempt to recreate the file each time a new line was reached. A data step by default loops `_N_` from 1 to the end of the input.